# Rails 3.1 newbie : where should I put javascript code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am developing **Rails 3.1** application, I get confused about where should I put my own javascript code(e.g. *my.js*) and where to put 3rd-party javascript library (e.g. *jQuery-UI*).

I know in the old version Rails, javascript should all goes into **public/javascripts/** directory, when I generate Rails 3.1 app, there is no **public/javascripts/** folder, but there is **app/assets/** and **verndor/assets/** and there is **application.js** in **app/assets**, I would like to ask:

1. in Rails 3.1 ,where should I put **my.js** and **jQuery-UI js** in Rails 3.1??
2. what is the **app/assets/application.js** supposed to do?
3. how can I include **my.js** and **jQuery-UI js** in my html page?

**----------------Am I right?----------**

Is `require_tree` in **application.js is** used to include 3rd-party libraries under **app/vendor/assets/javascript/**

and `require "something"` in **application.js** is used to include js file under **app/assets/javascripts/**?? Am I right?

Answer (score 7):

Put your own javascript & coffeescript under `app/assets/javascripts`.

Take a look inside `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`. When you ran `rails new APP` it should have added `//= require_tree .` to this file. [See section 2.3 for more](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

This is a special instruction that [Sprockets](http://jackdempsey.me/2011/04/22/rails-3-1-sprockets-and-coffeescript.html) understands that wil automatically include all files in the same directory as your `application.js` file and in subfolders below it.

If you want jquery and jquery-ui to be loaded your application.js file should look like

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

If you have [`gem 'jquery-rails'`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails) in your bundle, this gem has already added the jquery files to the asset pipeline for you, so you **don't have to worry about downloading them manually**.

In your head section of your application view you will want to include `javascript_include_tag "application"` in the head section. Chances are, if you used the generator, it's already there.

Please read up on the [Rails Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for more information.

---

The `.` in the line with `require_tree` is referencing the location of the current file. The `//=` operator is referencing the asset pipeline.

Placing a file in app/assets, lib/assets or vendor/assets will add it to the asset pipeline. [See section 2.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: @ Alex, you still get me confused, I am asking about the place where to put 3rd party library and where to put my own js file. And I am also confused about the usage and meaning of application.js . Is require_tree in application.js is used to include 3rd-party libraries under app/vendor/assets/javascript 
and require "something" in application.js is used to include js file under app/assets/javascripts?? Am I right?

Comment: In order to include a file that's in your asset pipeline, you should reference it in the correct order in your application.js. Your own javascript is excepted if you put it in `app/assets/javascripts` and use `require_tree .` in your application.js which is stored in this location.

Comment: the jQuery files are coming from [`gem 'jquery-rails'`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails)

Comment: Note that if you use the `jquery-ui` gem AND add the `jquery-ui` script manually, it'll cause problems. It's best to stick with the gem by itself.

Answer (score 5):

Ryan Bates has a good overview of the asset pipeline on Railscasts. It helped me out when I was trying to sort it out. http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline