# Rails javascript files (other than application.js) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on implementing jQuery into a rails project, and have this Javascript tag in the head of my application.html.erb file:

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

And if I put jQuery code into my application.js file, it works as expected in my application. However, if I put the jQuery code into any other .js files in my assets/javascripts folder (home.js, for example), it doesn't work as it should in my application.

Here's my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
```

It was my impression that the last line of that meant that all my other js files would be compiled into application.js, so having just the <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> in my application.html.erb file would be sufficient to make all my js files work -- is this a faulty assumption?

These are the contents of my home.js file -- this function works as it should when I put it into my application.js file directly but when it's in my home.js file instead it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h2").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: you are right. where is `home.js` placed? it should be in app/assets/javascripts/

Comment: Yep, that's where it is. It was created when I generated the associated controller and haven't moved it since, so I'm confused by the behavior here.

Comment: can you check your html source? see if it is in the head tag?

Comment: Yep -- weird, it's showing up, along with all my other js files (including application.js): <script src="/assets/home.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: can you look at any errors in the js when you load the page?

Comment: getting the same message in the server log for all the js files: Started GET "/assets/home.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-20 19:26:01 -0800
Served asset /home.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
[2013-02-20 19:26:01] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true

Comment: Your js file is inlcuded and functionality is not working then u have some mistake in ur code, check it again, And see the console log of ur browser, when u click on that element then function is called or may be some errors there.

Comment: not that, i mean js errors in the browser

Comment: in development your js files get loaded individually instead of being compiled. To disable that set `config.assets.debug = false` in `config/environments/development.rb`

Comment: Found it by going to the browser console log -- stupid mistake on my part, had CoffeeScript on at one point so there were lines at the top of another JS file with lines starting with # that were supposed to be comments rather than // after I made them just JS files. Thanks for leading me to the answer!

Comment: New here -- is there a way to accept a comment as the correct answer or does it need to be an actual answer?

Comment: You are going right, look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7763692/1970061  it might help you .

Answer (score 0):

Try to add //=my home in application.js file above //=require_tree .
Hope this helps.