# Where to install .js code in a Rails app so it gets inserted before /body ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is embarrassing but I have a small js code (embedded tag similar to google analytics), now I had put it in application.js file but it didn't worked. So I created some_random_code.js in javascripts folder in assets and put the code in it, but that code still didn't worked. Surprisingly when I put the code at before /body of application.html.erb, then the code works.

What am I doing wrong ? how to insert some javascript tag code before /body in application.html.erb or in any page ?

I searched and did found similar questions like [Rails 3.1 newbie : where should I put javascript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7763675/692622) but somehow those didn't solved my problem hence asking at SO

Thanks

Comment: @Deefour -  but there is so much js code that it looks ugly, I was wondering, if I could just put that code in some file and include it, what do you say ?

Comment: so putting it in application.html <head>  head doesnt work? also put the code within <script type="text/javascript"> </script> you may also have to put  <%= yield(:head) %> above it, ive added example in an answer, hopefully this is what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i use google analytics and placed the code within the head like so

```
<head>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

<%= yield(:head) %>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  //Google Analytics javascript code
 </script>
</head>
```