# Adding Javascritpt & CSS in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

For my view I need to have my view pick the styles from css file. Also there is some javascript code in my view. The problem is view is neither picking the styles nor the javascript code. This is the first time I am working on rails view with javascript so searched web for answers. I found some detailed explanation at below link but there are so many answers.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763675/rails-3-1-newbie-where-should-i-put-javascript-code
```

I tried by putting my javascript code in assets/javascripts/billings.js file and similarly the  css code in assets/stylesheets/billings.css file but it didn't work. I am assuming placing code here will work and the index.html.erb file of billings controller will pick this. Do i need to refer this path in my index file.
Below is the code in billings.js file

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#up").on('click',function(){
        $("#qty input").val(parseInt($("#qty input").val())+1);
    });

    $("#down").on('click',function(){
        $("#qty input").val(parseInt($("#qty input").val())-1);
    });

    $("#first").on('click',function(){
        $("ul").hide();
        $("#starter").show();


    });
    $("#drinkMenu").on('click',function(){
        $("ul").hide();
        $("#Drinks").show();
    });
    $("#vege").on('click',function(){
        $("ul").hide();
        $("#veg").show();
    });
    $("#last").on('click',function(){
        $("ul").hide();
        $("#special").show();
    });
});


</script>
```

index.html.erb file

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>System</title>


</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="tabelorder">
<label> Tabel Number:</label> <input type="number"  placeholder="Table NO.">
        <input type="search"  placeholder="Search Products" /> 

</div>

<div class="right-block">
<div class="RightHeader">
<a href="#" class="RightHeaderMenuItem" id="first">
 starter</a>
<a href="#" class="RightHeaderMenuItem" id="drinkMenu">
Drinks Menu</a>
<a href="#" class="RightHeaderMenuItem" id="vege">
Vegetarianas</a>
<a class="RightHeaderMenuItemLast" id="last">
Special Menu</a>
</div>
<div class="MenuItem">
<ul id="starter">
<li>starter</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul>
<ul id="Drinks">
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul>
<ul id="veg">
<li>vegetarianas</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul>
<ul id="special">
<li>special</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="table_list">
<button type="submit">Table 1</button>
<button type="submit">Table 2</button>
<button type="submit">Table 3</button>
<button type="submit">Table 4</button>
<button type="submit">Table 5</button>
<button type="submit">Table 6</button>
</div>
<div class="left-block">
    <!--<div class="LeftHeader">
        <input type="search"  placeholder="Search Products"/> 
    </div>-->
    <div class="LeftBorderBlock">
        <img src="images/grid2Whitepressed.png" height="60" />
        <div id="qty">

        <button type="button" id="up">+</button>
        <button type="button" id="down">-</button>
         <input type="number" value="0" />
        </div>


        <!-- <img  src="images/2.png" id="up">
        <img src="images/1.png" id="down" style="margin-top:-6.5%;">-->

    </div>
    <div class="LeftMiddleBlock">
    <div class="AddItem">
    <div class="AddItemDtailQty">2</div>
    <div class="AddItemDtail">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="AddItemDtailPrice">@$522</div>
     <div class="AddItemDtailPrice">$1044</div>
    <div class="CancelItemDtail"><img src="images/icon_error.png" height="20"/></div>
    </div>
     <div class="AddItem">
    <div class="AddItemDtailQty">2</div>
    <div class="AddItemDtail">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="AddItemDtailPrice">@$522</div>
     <div class="AddItemDtailPrice">$1044</div>
    <div class="CancelItemDtail"><img src="images/icon_error.png" height="20"/></div>
      </div>
     <div class="AddItem">
   <div class="AddItemDtailQty">2</div>
    <div class="AddItemDtail">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="AddItemDtailPrice">@$522</div>
     <div class="AddItemDtailPrice">$1044</div>
    <div class="CancelItemDtail"><img src="images/icon_error.png" height="20"/></div>
    </div>



    </div>
    <div class="LeftBorderBlock">
            <div class="calculationBill">
                <div class="LeftText">Subtotal</div>
                <div class="Righttext">$130.47</div>
            </div>
            <div class="calculationBill">
                <div class="LeftText">Tax</div>
                <div class="Righttext">$10.43</div>
            </div>
            <div class="calculationBill">
            <strong>
                    <div class="LeftText">Total</div>
                <div class="Righttext">$141.00</div></strong>

            </div>
            <div class="calculationBill">
            <div class="DividerLine"></div>
            <strong>
                    <div class="LeftText">To Pay</div>
                <div class="Righttext">$141.00</div></strong>
            </div>
    </div>
<button type="submit">Void</button> 
<button type="submit">Park</button>
<button type="submit">Notes</button>
<button type="submit">Discount</button>
<button type="submit">Pay</button>
</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I am using Rails 3.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to get JQuery javascript to work:

1. Add `gem "jquery-rails"` to your Gemfile and bundle it.
2. Run `rails generate jquery:install`
3. Add your code to `billings.js` under assets/javascript.
4. Ensure either `//= require_tree .` or `//= require billings` is in the `application.js` in assets/javascript.
5. Restart your rails server.

You should avoid including scripts in your own JS if possible.

CSS should have been included when you added it to billings.css.

**Edit**

It appears that your layout is not introducing the default JS and CSS for some reason.
At the top of your controller in Rails, it should look something like:

```
class NameofMyAppController < ApplicationController
```

If you are using a custom layout (e.g.

```
class NameOfMyAppController < ApplicationController
  layout :custom_layout
```

Then you need to edit that custom layout to add the standard JS and CSS tags to your custom_layout.html.erb inside `<head></head>`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the crisp and clear solution I was looking for. The first 4 steps were already in place, just I didn't restart server. But after restart too I am facing same issue. I have updated my post with index. html.erb file. Could you please suggest if I am still missing something. Thanks for everything.

Comment: Edited with more things to try.

Comment: One other comment: you know you should only have everything between the `<body>` and `</body>` tags inside the .html.erb file for your controller's action, right? Everything else will be rendered by the default layout.... I recommend you read all about [layouts and rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.1.1/layouts_and_rendering.html).